# BCM4311 Wireless Not Working with Drivers Installed

Tags: wireless, 12.10, broadcom

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my old Compaq/Hp Preario V3000 to replace Windows XP.
Every thing works fine except I'm getting no wireless network options in the network drop down menu. I'm using a cable at the moment.

Wirless chipset is:

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
08:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection (rev 02)
```

I ran rfkill:

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I also ran iwconfig and got this

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

In the additional drivers it says: "Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)"

Any help to resolve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please hook up the ethernet temporarily and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```

Is it working now?

Comment: Sweet! Nice one chili555. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `b43` to the end of the `/etc/modules` file. I've heard this can take care of the module waking it up when the computer starts.