# Install Broadcom driver

Tags: 11.04, broadcom

I have a live USB of Ubuntu 11.04. I  trying to get the WiFi to work.

There seem to be two options. Install the driver in live USB mode, then have it gone after the required restart or install Ubuntu to the hard drive and have the computer try to download the WiFi driver from the internet (which will never work because I don't have WiFi).

I have the driver currently installed in the live USB but can't use it until I restart, which deletes the driver...

What should I do?

Note:
I am more interested in finding a way to activate the drivers that I just installed without restarting than finding what drivers to use (since these are almost certainly the correct drivers)

The card is BCM4311

Edit:
OK, the problem is solved but I still would like to know how someone is supposed to do this. Since the drivers were on the live USB there must be a way to get them off of there and use them on the fully installed version. I would like to know how to do that.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan that won't work because I can't download the suggested drivers without internet access.

Comment: You're right that [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) doesn't sufficiently address this case. Maybe [How do I install additional drivers with both wired and wireless failing?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236651/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers-with-both-wired-and-wireless-failing) or [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) will help.

Comment: @Eliah Kagen after reading the second link you provided i remembered that I had an old wifi adapter and used that to get around not having drivers so I voted up your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a USB WiFi adapter and used that to connect to the internet and download the drivers.